# Weird exception in linkbutton in a datalist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have written this datalist :

```
       <div class="story" runat="server">
   <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="412px">
                  <SeparatorTemplate>
                    <hr />
                  </SeparatorTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat ="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' PostBackUrl='<%#Eval("Url")%>' />          
                    <br />
                  Description:
                  <asp:Label ID="new" Text='<%#Eval("Description") %>' runat="server" />                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:DataList>




      </div>
```

It raises an exception saying that the linkbutton has to be placed in a tag that contains runat="server" although it exists. 
Here is the trace

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Le contrôle 'DataList2_ctl00_LinkButton1' de type 'LinkButton' doit être placé dans une balise form avec runat=server.]
   System.Web.UI.Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) +8689747
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) +39
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer) +20
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +20
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItem.RenderItemInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, Boolean extractRows, Boolean tableLayout) +51
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataListItem.RenderItem(HtmlTextWriter writer, Boolean extractRows, Boolean tableLayout) +57
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.System.Web.UI.WebControls.IRepeatInfoUser.RenderItem(ListItemType itemType, Int32 repeatIndex, RepeatInfo repeatInfo, HtmlTextWriter writer) +64
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeatInfo.RenderVerticalRepeater(HtmlTextWriter writer, IRepeatInfoUser user, Style controlStyle, WebControl baseControl) +262
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeatInfo.RenderRepeater(HtmlTextWriter writer, IRepeatInfoUser user, Style controlStyle, WebControl baseControl) +27
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer) +208
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataList.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +30
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +32
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +134
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +19
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1266
```

Comment: i think the error may be that it needs to be in a form tag with runat=server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be in a [form](http://www.codetoad.com/asp.net/aspnetcontrols4.asp) tag `<form runat="server"></form>` with the runat server attribute.

The following link talks about the runat server attribute:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1547244/3784993.aspx